# Cycle Through a Object Class and generate dynamic fields for each Value

Tags: c#, winforms, class, object

So I have an Class Object:

```
public class BaseFields
        {
            public List<string> incidentType { get; set; }
            public string owner { get; set; }
            public string queue { get; set; }
            public string priority { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
            public long startedDate { get; set; }
            public long endedDate { get; set; }
            public long createdAt { get; set; }
            public string createdBy { get; set; }
            public long updatedAt { get; set; }
            public string updatedBy { get; set; }
        }
```

I am using the Json parser to populate the object. And I would like to present that object as fields on a Form. but, my complete Class has 250 values. this is only a snippet. and creating a form with 250 text boxes is going to be a lot of coding and messy.

I would like to find a way to create a field on a WinForm dynamically for each value once I fill the Object from a Json download.

Unless you guys know a better way to present Json output into a WinForm?

To give some additional Context, I am pulling incidents from a Service Now instance. listing the incident numbers in a ListView. When the user selects an incident I would like to present the contexts of the incident in a form via a API call, parse the Json and present on the form as field mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a way:

adding a field for each value and moving however, it wasnt as functional as I hoped.